# Magento: Show category image, when product image is unavailable

Tags: magento

Instead of displaying a boring image when the product has no images (placeholder), I would like to show the Catagory image instead of a general placeholder. I've been searching around @SO, but didn't view any solutions.

Below is a snippet from the media.phtml which shows the image.

```
    $_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(265).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
    echo '<a class="' . $borderClass . '" title="' . $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()) . '" onclick="return hs.expand(this);" href="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') . '">' . $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image') . '</a>';

//--> $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(265)
```

Anybody has an idea/solution? Magento 1.5, by the way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can another "boring picture" for no image in magento configuration. This "boring picture" is called placeholder.

Another option for you is:

```
1. Load first of product categories.
2. Get category image
3. Put category image instead of default "boring picture"
```

**UPDATE 1**

To load product category on category page:

```
$currentCat = $_product->getCategory();
$_product->getCategoryCollection();
$_product->getCategoryIds();
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
```

To get category image:

```
$_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
```

Therefore check if product has no image, and if not replace product image with category image.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve, but I have no idea how..?

Comment: Simplicity is the key; thanks Jake. I was thinking way to difficult, many thanks!